# jquery didnt start function

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

```
function getAccount() {
    if ($("#mLogIn").has('<input id="mMail" class="bg-whitesmoke" type="email" placeholder="E-mail-Adresse" />')) {
        $("#mLogIn").remove('<input id="mMail" class="bg-whitesmoke" type="email" placeholder="E-mail-Adresse" />');
    } 
    else {
        $('<input id="mMail" class="bg-whitesmoke" type="email" placeholder="E-mail-Adresse" />').insertAfter('#mUser');
    };
};
```

This is my function. I don't know why it does not work? Do you have any clues?

Comment: I'm not sure that's how `.has` works. You must pass either a selector or a DOM element.

Comment: 'It doesn't work' is never enough information. Why does it not work? Do you get an error? What should happen? What does happen?

Comment: No, it just does nothing. I click on a link and nothing happens.

Comment: The console must say something if the code does nothing.

Comment: <a href="#" onclick="getAccount();" id="mLogInLinkLeft">

Comment: Check if $('#mLogIn') is undefined. Is selector found?

Comment: Man, i got it. Its ok. Thanks.

Comment: What was it then? That `has` doesn't seem like it would work as you'd expect...

Comment: Yes, i missunderstood the .has. I will look for another method and i am sure it will work. Thanks for the fast help

Answer (score 0):

Do you make a call to that function?

put a:

```
   alert ('before function');
    alert ('after function');
```

to make sure you don't have javascript errors

Comment: Also, to make sure all is fine you just open the console. This does not answers the Q anyway cause it's not the way `.has()` is meant to be used.

Answer (score 0):

As @elclanrs said, your usage of [`.has`](http://api.jquery.com/has/) is wrong: It does expect either a selector or a DOM element; you're passing a html string. Instead, use this:

```
function getAccount() {
    if ($("#mLogIn").has('#mMail').length) {
        $("#mMail").remove();
    } else {
        $('<input id="mMail" class="bg-whitesmoke" type="email" placeholder="E-mail-Adresse" />').insertAfter('#mUser');
    }
}
```

Comment: You might want to use `#` in `$("#mMail").remove();`

Answer (score 0):

The .has function will search for a selector instead of a full string. Instead of

`.has('<input id="mMail" class="bg-whitesmoke" type="email" placeholder="E-mail-Adresse" />')`

you should use `.has("#mMail")`